# Get percent rank for a given value in a given table column

Tags: postgresql, statistics, aggregate-functions, percentile

I have a Postgres table with about 500k rows. One of the columns called *score* has values ranging from 0-1. The data is not normally distributed.

Say I have an observation of 0.25. I'd like to find out where this would fall in the distribution of the *score* column. This is sometimes referred to as the percent rank.

E.G. a value of 0.25 is in the 40th percentile. This would mean that a value of 0.25 is larger than 40% of the observations in the table.

I know I can calculate a frequency distribution with something like below but this feel like overkill when all I want is a percentile value.

```
select k, percentile_disc(k) within group (order by mytable.score)
from mytable, generate_series(0.01, 1, 0.01) as k
group by k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the hypothetical-set aggregate function **`percent_rank()`**:

```
SELECT percent_rank(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score)
FROM   mytable;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-HYPOTHETICAL-TABLE)

> Computes the relative rank of the hypothetical row, that is (`rank` - 1) / (total rows - 1). The value thus ranges from 0 to 1 inclusive.

Comment: this is great. would you expect an index on the score field to improve performance on this?

Comment: @jotamon: Postgres has to take all qualifying rows into account to come up with a percentage, so indexes are of limited use. Can still help for tables with wide rows, where the index is substantially smaller than the table. Test with `EXPLAIN`.